# How to delete from javascript object array in angular with typescript

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript, object

My object array looks like this:

```
0: {Name: "Albert", Id: 32}
1: {Name: "George", Id: 34}
2: {Name: "Jane", Id: 35}
```

The request is successfully done, but my array stays the same. When I refresh my app, the item (student) is deleted. 
When i Click the delete button i get: INDEX:-1

What am I doing wrong?

student.component.html

```html
<thead>
<tr style="font-weight: 500;font-size:15px;">
  <th data-field="id">Id</th>
  <th data-field="name">Display Name</th>
  <th>Delete</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr *ngFor="let student of students;">
  <td>{{ student.Id }}</td>
  <td>{{ student.Name }}</td>
  <td><span class="ion-android-delete" (click)="onDelete(student.Id)"> </span></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
```

student.component.ts

```js
onDelete(studentId: number) {
    if (window.confirm('Are you sure you want to delete?')) {
      var index = this.students.indexOf(studentId, 1);
        while (this.students.indexOf(studentId) !== -1) {
        this.students.splice(this.students.indexOf(studentId), 1);
      }

      this.studentService.deleteStudent(studentId)
        .subscribe(
        (response) => console.log(response));
        (error) => console.log(error));
    }
}
```

student.service.ts

```js
deleteStudent(studentId: number) {    
  return this.http.delete......

            (response: Response) => {
                const data = response.json();
                return data;
            }
            )
            .catch(
            (error: Response) => {
                console.log(error);
                return Observable.throw(error);
            }
            );
}
```

---

Edited code:

```
 onDeleteAgent(agentId: number) {
    if (window.confirm('Are you sure you want to delete?')) {

      while (this.agents.indexOf(this.agents) !== -1) {
        console.log(this.agents.indexOf(this.agents));
        this.agents.splice(this.agents.indexOf(this.agents), 1);
      }

      this.agentService.deleteAgent(agentId)
        .subscribe(
        (response) => console.log(response),
        (error) => console.log(error));
    }
  }
```

Comment: your students array contains students, not student IDs. So indexOf(studentId) is always going to be -1. Pass the student, not the studentId, as argument.

Comment: var index = this.students.indexOf(studentId, 1);
console.log("INDEX:" + index)
this way I get -1 also..

Comment: You didn't read my comment. Read it again, carefully.

Comment: i think i get what you are saying, added the edited code but it still stays -1 :D

Comment: Now you're looking for `this.agents` inside `this.agents`. This doesn't make sense. The array doesn't contain itself, does it? Again, read what I said: *Pass the student, not the studentId, as argument.*. You're still passing agentId, which is a number, as argument to your method. Pass the agent itself. And get the index of the agent passed as argument inside the array of agents (which contains agents, not numbers). Also, you don't need any loop to delete one agent from an array.

Comment: thank you, i misunderstood in the first time, and I am sending now the whole student on the html file. thanks! if you give me an answer i will select as an answer!

Comment: @PeterSmith i added a answer with new logic. it perfectly works  for me. let me know is it is worke in your situation?

Answer (score 0):

Your onDelete method is quite wrong. If you really have to start from the sudentId, do the following instead:

```js
onDelete(studentId: number) {
  if (!window.confirm('Are you sure you want to delete?')) {
    return;
  }

  var student = this.students.find(s => s.Id === studentId);
  var index = array.indexOf(student);

  if (index > -1) {
    array.splice(index, 1);
  }
}
```

You can also just filter the array like this (make sure you can reassign the array without any issue first though):

```js
onDelete(studentId: number) {
  if (window.confirm('Are you sure you want to delete?')) {
    this.students = this.students.filter(s => s.Id !== studentId);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

student.component.html

```
<thead>
<tr style="font-weight: 500;font-size:15px;">
  <th data-field="id">Id</th>
  <th data-field="name">Display Name</th>
  <th>Delete</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr *ngFor="let student of students;let i = index">
  <td>{{ student.Id }}</td>
  <td>{{ student.Name }}</td>
  <td><span class="ion-android-delete" (click)="onDelete(student.Id,i)"> </span></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
```

student.component.ts

```
onDelete(studentId: number,index) {
    if (window.confirm('Are you sure you want to delete?')) {
        this.students.splice(index, 1);    
      this.studentService.deleteStudent(studentId)
        .subscribe(
        (response) => console.log(response));
        (error) => console.log(error));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Inside student.component.ts , Your Delete method is wrong(mismatch student id and object Array), Here is simplified version of delete method , It's good practices delete object after received the server response

```
onDelete(studentId: number) {
    if (window.confirm('Are you sure you want to delete?')) {      

      this.studentService.deleteStudent(studentId)
        .subscribe(
        (response) => {
             for(let i=0;i<this.students.length;i++){
               if(this.students[i].Id == studentId){
               this.students.splice(i,1);
                break;
             }
        });
        (error) => console.log(error));
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Just use `filter` and filter out the student to delete and set a new object reference using the `spread` operator to `this.students`.

```
onDelete(studentId: number) {
  if (window.confirm('Are you sure you want to delete?')) {
    this.students = [...this.students.filter((student:any) => student.Id !== studentId)];
  }
...
```

**Note:** The spread operator is not required, but is rather a good habit and best practice to use immutable objects.

**Without the spread operator:**

```
this.students = this.students.filter((student:any) => student.Id !== studentId);
```

Comment: Could the downvoter please explain why it was downvoted?

Comment: Well I didn't downvote anybody here but I must admit I don't understand the `[` and `...`. Are you trying to abbreviate your code? This makes it hard to read and... longer!

Comment: The `...` is the spread operator which will create a new reference object and set that to `this.students`. It's a best practice.

Comment: Oh my bad, didn't know about this one. Down vote still unexplained then.